# How to determine which process is using a port in Linux

Tags: python, linux, rethinkdb

I'm currently running RethinkDB on its default port, because if I point my browser to `localhost:8080` I see the RethinkDB web interface:

[image]

I'd like to close RethinkDB and re-open it on another port using the `--port-offset` argument. However, so far I haven't been able to close it from within Python using the `conn.close()` method.

Instead, I'd like to try a brute-force approach by simply killing the process using that port. I tried to determine which process that is by using `netstat`, but that doesn't bring up any results:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ netstat -a | grep 8080
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$
```

How can I kill the RethinkDB process to make the port available again?

Comment: `netstat -nlp`. Best with `sudo`!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
1.  lsof -i:8080
2.  kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)
or
2 . kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d)'s comment, I determined the process using `netstat -nlp`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ netstat -nlp | grep 8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2229/rethinkdb  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2229/rethinkdb  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8080                :::*                    LISTEN      2229/rethinkdb
```

The arguments stand for

- `numeric` (show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or usernames)
- `listening` (show only listening sockets (these are omitted by default))
- `program` (show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs)

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome answer @codespy .
I did a bash file and wrote it like this.

## !/bin/bash

Kill $(lsof -t -i  :8000)

And save it and script file.

And made executable by
$chmod +x script_filename

Now I run just by entering
./script_filename

Answer (score 0):

To find out the pid or all the info about particular port as by which accused

```
sudo lsof -i :PORT_NUMBER
```

To kill the process or event

```
kill -9 PID
```

example:-

```
harshit@harshit:~/Desktop/edwin-diaz/cms$ lsof -i :4111
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    9215 harshit   33u  IPv6 297470      0t0  TCP *:4111 (LISTEN)
harshit@harshit:~/Desktop/edwin-diaz/cms$ kill -9 9215
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution, some Unix/Linus has the command **ss** which is the new generation command similar to **netstat**, you could simply type the following:

```
ss -ltnp
```

`-p` list process number

`-l` list listening sockets

`-t` list tcp sockets

`-n` list port number instead of conventional name (21 instead of ssh)

**check the man page for more info**