# I am getting this error, can you help me to solve it?

Tags: spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDTKP.png)file application.properties

[image]

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-28 15:25:12.220 ERROR 39244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I changed the ports in the application.properties file. but still get the same error.
At first I ran it automatically, but the next day I ran it again and the problem was like this.. I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you try doing the thing that it tells you to do?

Comment: 8080 already in use. Close whatever is using it first.

Comment: sorry, but i have changed a lot of ports, but still get the error message used. can you give me 1 port to test? thank you

Comment: How and where did you change ports?

Comment: I replaced the port in the file application.properties @dunni

Comment: @dunni 
At first I ran it automatically, but the next day I ran it again and the problem was like this.. I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: First you should check, what process is already listening on that port. See the following Q&A for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows or that one for Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974335/how-to-determine-which-process-is-using-a-port-in-linux or that one for Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error. There is another application running on port 8080.

Select a new port to expose or terminate the other application.

Comment: i have changed a lot of ports, but they all say used, can you give me a port, so i can test it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try netstat

```
 netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8080
```

or Macosx

```
 lsof -i tcp:8080
```

or Linux

```
 netstat -vanp --tcp | grep 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally port `8080` is generally used for a Web Server and I believe is the default for local development with Tomcat; so most likely you have something you have developed running on that port still. I've had this before when Intellij crashes and the Tomcat instance isn't stopped.

You can easily kill it by doing the following:

**WINDOWS**

**Step 1:** Open up the command console (cmd.exe), depending on your privileges you may need to run in Administrator; run the following command (Replace `<PORT>` with your port number):

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>
```

[image]

this will give you a list of services/processes running on port `8080`. What you are interested in is the `PID` which is a number located at the end.

**Step 2:** In the same command console run the following command using the `PID` number (Replace `<PID>` with your number):

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

[image]

Port `8080` should now be free for you to restart your application.

**MACOS**

For doing the same for MAC please follow this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/609794/kill-what-ever-is-running-on-port-8080) (Answered copied)

> Find out what Process ID (pid) is using the required port (e.g port
> 5434).
>
> `ps aux | grep 5434` Kill that process:
>
> `kill -9 <pid>`

**LINUX**

For doing the same for Linux please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux) (Answered copied)

> This `fuser 8080/tcp` will print you PID of process bound on that port.
>
> And this `fuser -k 8080/tcp` will kill that process.
>
> Works on Linux only. More universal is use of `lsof -i4` (or 6 for IPv6).

***Disclaimer:** I only checked this on WINDOWS so if using MAC or LINUX and those links worked give credit to those users please.*

Comment: i did your way, but still not able to handle the error. Yesterday, I ran the program normally, but now I don't understand why this problem occurs

Comment: After killing port `8080` if you run `netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>` again does it say something is using the port still?

Comment: i tried it under macos, but it didn't solve the problem